# PHP Upgradation for windows

Tags: php, php-5.3, porting, php-5.6

I'm new to PHP . I'm currently using Windows 10 on my local machine.

I'm using the following PHP version for developing my PHP project:

php -v //command run at terminal to know the `PHP` version installed

PHP 5.3.13
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
Now a couple of days back a new latest stable release of PHP version (PHP 5.6.0) was released by the PHP development team.

My question is, as I'm using a PHP version on my local machine which is too old, and also all PHP versions lower than 5.4 are officially unsupported or announced end-of-life, should I go for PHP 5.6.0?

If your answer is yes, please explain me how to do it? Will the code I written in my project work properly after this migration? What changes I'll need to do?

If your answer is no, please explain me in detail why?

Before asking this question I've gone through Google and PHP documentation. There I found migration notes for following version migrations:

```
**5.3.x->5.4.x


5.4.x->5.5.x



5.5.x->5.6.x**
```

Didn't get how to migrate from PHP 5.3.10 to PHP 5.6.0.

So can someone please help me in this regard?
I need to know in which direction I need to proceed.
If you need any further information regarding my issue please do let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29272612/php-version-upgrade-5-3-25-to-5-6

Comment: "should I go for PHP 5.6.0?" ... Yes. Except, go for 5.6.23 rather than 5.6.0.